# How to add a fixed sidebar

Tags: css

I want to add a fixed sidebar like in the picture below.

[image]

How is that possible?

```
Appreciate any suggestion.
```

**[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/G8DCg/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

used to this

> fixed position

```
.sidebar{
position:fixed;
left:0;
width:250px; // width change to according your left bar side
top:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hVRXx/1/)**

Comment: Is this a browser safe solution? Some negative effects or is it supported by the majority? Thanks for the respons:)

Comment: Thank you. But, I want it to be full height. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

```
.SomeClass { position: fixed }
```

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle might solve your problem, with right column being flexible and left column fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/R5TZH/

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="columns">
         <div class="right-col">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum
        </div>    
     </div>  
    <div class="left-col">
                <a class="selected" href="#">05 <br><strong>Today</strong></a>
                <a href="#">06 <br><strong>TOM</strong></a>
                <a href="#">07 <br><strong>MON</strong></a>
                <a href="#">08 <br><strong>TUE</strong></a>
                <a href="#">09 <br><strong>WED</strong></a>
                <a href="#">08 <br><strong>THU</strong></a>
                <a href="#">09 <br><strong>FRI</strong></a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.left-col {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #434345;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -100%;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 80px;
}

.left-col a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}


.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}


.right-col {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background:red;
    height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for fixed side bar, style

```
position:fixed;
```

this will do but not in chrome, so you may use this

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
width:180px;// you may change as per your requirement
```

this works in all browsers :)

Edit : updated fiddle with content div

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/nkprH/5/
```

I hope this will do, for more answer post some of your work in details, thank you

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I should proceed so that i can get fullwidth content on the right side of the sidebar?

Comment: you can do it in many ways, create another div with `left:181px;` post some of your html and css code, or create a fiddle so that we can guide you better, thank you.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could take a look:)

Comment: I was busy so late :) take a look in the answer above